# SharePoint 2013 "Working On It" a lot during development with no CPU/disk activity

Tags: development, 2013, performance

When doing anything that requires SharePoint to recycle, like deploying a project to SharePoint from Visual Studio, it takes forever for SharePoint to spin up again.

The deployment is about the same speed as with SharePoint 2010, but the wait time till the site is ready to use again is agonizingly slow, ~30-60 seconds sometimes.

While SharePoint is "Working On It" I can see in the Resource Monitor that there is almost no CPU activity (~10%) and there is still memory free, so what is holding up SharePoint, and what can I do to make it go faster?

[image]

**Software:**

- Windows Server 2012 (running DC)
- SQL Server 2012 dev edition
- SharePoint Server 2012
- Visual Studio 2012
- My computer is connected to the Internet

**Hareware:**

- I5-2520M 2.5 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 2 x Intel SSD 330

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is only the dialog that hangs? Did you try opening another window to check whether deployment has finished? :)

Comment: It does not look like it is just the dialog. Closing and reopening the browser window does not affect it. It continues to display the spinner and the text "working on it".

Answer (score 1):

Does your machine have Internet access?

I have seen really slow app pool recycles / iisresets due to timeouts whilst waiting to resolve the Microsoft Certificate Revoked List Servers http://crl.microsoft.com. There are various checks when these processes start for the digital signatures to make sure that the assemblies are valid and the signatures havent been revoked.

See the following blog post:-
http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/09/20/certificate-revocation-list-check-and-sharepoint-2010-without-an-internet-connection/

Comment: Hi Simon. My computer does have internet access, and I have tried the various tricks to handle timeouts in regards to crl.microsoft.com. It has not solved the problem, and running stsadm -help is almost instant, so I do not think that is my problem.

Comment: What are the disks doing? If you start up Performance Monitor and check the Logical Disk Drives Average Disk Queue Length. If the values are over 2 then the O/S is waiting for the disk subsystem. I would suggest splitting the DC / SQL onto separate VMs too. I have a DC with 1GB, SQL with 4GB and SharePoint has 8GB but then I have 16GB of RAM available.

Comment: Disk Queue Length never passes 0.02, so I don't think it is a disk performance issue.

Comment: Definately doesnt seem to be that. What content is the page loading? Is there any content that would use Service Applications, such as Search or BCS? Have a look in the ULS log using ULSViewer tool to see if there is activity there.

Comment: Search service is disabled already. No BCS at all, it is just a standard Team Site with two custom lists, nothing else. Ill download the ULSViewer and report back.

Comment: OK, been looking through the logs. Nothing springs out, but then again, not sure what I am looking for. I've uploaded the latest log file here: http://dl.egilhansen.com/1FMYXN1-DEV-20130208-1250.log

Comment: So it looks like you deploy your solution each time, is that right? If thats the case then that will take some time but you can be more efficient. Though it will depend on the type of change you are making. Download the CKS:Dev extension for Visual Studio. For example If you are just changing code then this will help by giving you an option to deploy your binaries as part of the process and then recycle the app pool after the binaries have been copied that will definately speed up your build/debug cycle.

Comment: As far as I can see, the CKS extension is only for VS2010/SP2010. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm good point, I do have it installed for VS2012 but not for SP2013 project.